# Convert nvarchar to numeric in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having problem with `b.strpay88Amt` column. The `b.strpay88Amt` column is a `nvarchar` datatype.  This error is

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
select distinct 
    b.strCostCentreID, b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, strPayTypeCode, 
    tblMachine.strDesc as KioskName, 
    (SUM(b.dblPaidAmt)) as RM, (SUM(b.strIpay88Amt)) as pay88AmtRM,
    (SUM(b.dblPaidAmt)) - (SUM(b.strIpay88Amt)) RMVariance, 
    (select STUFF((select  ','  + strProdType 
                   from tblCurrTrx as a  
                   where a.strPOSOnlineRefNo = b.strPOSOnlineRefNo 
                   for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')) as Agency   
from 
    tblCurrTrx as b 
inner join 
    tblMachine on b.strMachID = tblMachine.strMachID 
where
    strPaymentMethod = '2' 
    and (dtmTrans >= '1/21/2020')  
    and (strTransStatus = '01')
group by
    b.strCostCentreID, b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, b.strPayTypeCode, tblMachine.strDesc
```

Comment: You'll need to use `cast` or `convert` to convert your nvarchar value to a numeric value.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this query above. ?

Comment: Start with the sql server official documentation for cast and convert, and when you get stuck ask.

Comment: Of course the best thing would be to store your numeric data in a numeric datatype. Storing is as a string is going to cause plenty of issues now and in the future.

Comment: Why is this column that data type in the first place? Is it possible to change it?

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with ASP.NET or VB.NET so I removed those tags. Please only add relevant tags. SQL is SQL, regardless of the language used to write the application that executes it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions. These functions convert an expression of one data type to another. Your code will look something like this.
Below I will give a closer example.

```
SELECT b.strpay88Amt AS c_name , CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),b.strpay88Amt) AS b.strpay88Amt
  From tblCurrTrx
   as b 
  where something
```

However, the value of the column may not always be numeric. So it's best to check it out first.
You can also use CAST. The full documentation is available you can check them.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15